# Root element in axis2.xml

Tags: java, apache-axis

So I'm really hoping this question will be closed as obvious and I just don't know where to look. I looked in [the axis2 documentation](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/axis2config.html#Global_Configuration) but I cannot find what to call the root element in axis2.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After placing this bounty I found [this blog post](http://www.nandana.org/2008/08/want-to-run-apache-axis2-behind-proxy.html) which stated it is `<axisconfig name="AxisJava2.0">`.